# Restriction of the Steinberg representation

Tags: representation-theory

Let $G_{n}=GL(n,F)$, where $F$ a locally compact non-Archimedean field, $St_{G_{n}}$ the Steinberg representation of $G_{n}$, and $B$ the standard Borel subgroup of $G_{n}$.

We denote $\pi_{n}$ the representation $ind_{B}^{G_{n}}(Res_{B}^{G_{n}}St_{G_{n}})$, where $ind_{B}^{G_{n}}$ means the compactly induced representation (but it's a same with $Ind_{B}^{G_{n}}$ because $G_{n}/B$ is compact).

For $n=2$, it is easy to prove that $\pi_{2}\simeq ind_{T}^{G_{2}}1_{T}$, where $T$ is the diagonal Torus of $G_{2}$.

For $n>2$, I think that $\displaystyle \pi_{n}\simeq \bigoplus_{M}ind_{M}^{G_{n}}1_{M}$, where $M$ range the set of standard Levi subgroups of $G_{n}$, but I don't have an idea to prove this.

It's possible that this result is true and if it is, can someone give me an idea for the proof.

Answer (score 1):

Your claim for $n=2$ is not true. The trivial representation of $GL(2,o)$ is contained in $\pi_2$ but not in the Steinberg representation, which is not spherical.

For $n>2$, the same arguments hold true disproving your conjecture.